# Biggest value to consider when looking at perfect root of a number

Tags: roots, radicals

I have been pondering the following question: when considering perfect roots of a number, what are the smallest and largest values one should consider?

Obviously, the smallest to consider is 2, there is no point in considering the 1st root of a number. But is there really a largest value for any number to consider when looking for a perfect root?

Say for example we take the number 10: the smallest perfect root to consider is 2. But what would you say the largest is?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking, essentially, for which integers $n \geq 2$ that a number $x$ could have $\sqrt[n]x$ as an integer, and what the smallest/largest values of $n$ could be in this context (if just insofar as a relation with $x$)?

Comment: You shouldn't change your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is $n$, the largest is $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$.  If the square of that is $n$, you have found a perfect root.  No perfect root can be larger.  For your example, $\lfloor \sqrt {10} \rfloor=3$ and when we see $3^2=9 \neq 10$ we are done.

Comment: The cube root is always smaller than the square root, so once you get up to the square root you have already checked possible cube roots.  For example, if $n=125$ we would check numbers from $2$ to $\lfloor \sqrt {125} \rfloor=11$.  Along the way we would check $5$ and find $5^3=125$.